# How to add datepicker and timepicker to Django forms.SplitDateTimeField using field_classes?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form that splits the date and time from a datetime field in the model.

```
class BooksForm(forms.ModelForm):

        class Meta:
            model = Books
            fields = '__all__'
            field_classes = {'datetime_created': forms.SplitDateTimeField }
```

How can I add the classes `datepicker` and `timepicker` to the widget `date_attrs` and `time_attrs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add attrs to each field by passing them to a [SplitDateTimeWidget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.SplitDateTimeWidget)

```
field_classes = {
    'datetime_created': forms.SplitDateTimeField
}
widgets = {
    'datetime_created': SplitDateTimeWidget(
        date_attrs={'class': 'datepicker'},
        time_attrs={'class': 'timepicker'},
    )
}
```

Comment: thanks, unfortunately that gives me  `TypeError: 'SplitDateTimeField' object is not callable`

Comment: Sorry, you should pass the widget in the `widgets` attr of the Meta, updated